# Reading yes/no fields from Access DB yields DBnull

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2007

I am adding a column/field to an existing Access database as a yes/no field so that there is a checkbox displayed for user input/editing from within Access tools as well as external programmatically.
I create the column in the table with this SQL statement 
`"ALTER TABLE tablename ADD COLUMN UpdateLocked YESNO"`. 
(I learned from MS documents that I can't enter a DEFAULT portion to this statement!)

After the creation, and anytime later on startup, I create an adapter by:

```
OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter();
adapter.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tablename";
DataTable[] dtSchema = adapter.FillSchema(DBname, SchemaType.Source);
adapter.Fill(DataSet name);   //Dataset used in DataGridView object
```

The effect I see is:

1. The added column schema is correctly shown as Boolean in the VS 2012 debugger.
2. The column is shown as a '{}' uninitialized value in the "item array" instead of true/false as other already existing YES/NO columns do.
3. Manually entered records in the Access DB with a true or false condition don't display in the DataGridView that uses the DataSet. No matter the value.
4. If I use the DataGridView to enter a true/false in various records of the view that uses this DataSet, the column/field schema is now "corrected" and a true/false is correctly displayed in the "item array" debugger display instead of the {} uninitialized value.

I want it to allow correctly reading the YESNO field data, but changing the syntax of the creation SQL or the SELECT statement have no effect.
Previously created YESNO columns display correctly, is there a different way to do the ALTER statement creating the column that I can use?

The failure of the ALTER OleDb command attempting to set default is one item that can be fixed with an Update command to set all of the new records field values just after adding.  The primary concern I have is not being able to read the YESNO stored values at all in my DataGridView column checkboxes. The values aren't initialized during the adapter.Fill(). (Displays a {} value in Debugger.)

Comment: OleDbDataAdaptter is a mistype. Edited.

Comment: I was unable to recreate your issue. When I used my own code I got a found a proper `false` value (Type: `object {bool}`) in the [UpdateLocked] column of the DataTable for all existing rows. When I tried to use your code the C# 2010 compiler choked on `adapter.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM tablename";`: "Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand'.

Comment: Thank you for checking.  I solved the problem via another method.

Comment: Good to hear that you got it sorted out. Please consider taking a moment to post an answer explaining your solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found that the only way I could get the YESNO field to init properly was to initialize each Boolean to false after I created the field programmatically with a subsequent "`UPDATE tablename SET fieldname  = false`".  Thank you for looking at my question.  After setting the default this way, it seemed to work fine.  This really seemed unnecessary, but it worked.